# Getting Symbols on top of a Sigma

Tags: symbols

Trying to get this equation working within latex but having trouble getting it working I did try the following

```
\begin{equation}
  \mathlarger {( I * K)_{xy} = \Sigma^{h}_{i=1} \Sigma^{w}_{j=1} K}
\end{equation}{}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Replace `\Sigma` by `\sum`.

Comment: please always instead of code snippet provide complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` folowed with packages related to your problem, `\begin{document}` your code snippet and ending with ˙\document}`. by this you will help us to help you. if `\sum^{h}_{i=1}` will not help, tra `\sum\limits^{h}_{i=1}`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The correct symbol is `\sum` (for “summation”), not `\Sigma`. Also there is no reason for `\mathlarger`. Don't add `{}` after `\end{equation}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % recommended
\usepackage{relsize} % for \mathlarger

\begin{document}

The following display is wrong under many respects: the symbol
should be \verb|\sum| and not \verb|\Sigma|; also there is no
reason to make the symbols larger.
\begin{equation}
  \mathlarger {( I * K)_{xy} = \Sigma^{h}_{i=1} \Sigma^{w}_{j=1} K}
\end{equation}{}
This is the correct way to typeset the formula
\begin{equation}
(I * K)_{xy} = \sum^{h}_{i=1} \sum^{w}_{j=1} K
\end{equation}
Note that the empty group like in \verb|\end{equation}{}| is 
actually harmful: can you spot the misalignment?

\end{document}
```

[image]