# No spacing after \Sigma?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, symbols, math-operators

There seems to be barely any spacing (if at all) after \Sigma, making it hard to read. Is this normal? Is there any way around it?

```
 $ \Sigma_{v \in V} \alpha $
```

Output:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: Add your own horizontal space. See [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/5764)

Comment: why don't you use `\sum`?

Comment: `\Sigma` is a normal greek letter so has no spacing just as `abc` has no extra spacing, if you mean summation operator then use `\sum` which is a different character and also specified as a math operator so has different spacing.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409380/getting-symbols-on-top-of-a-sigma

Comment: there are spacing symbols defined. the one i use most is: \, but others exist as well ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use `\sum`, not `\Sigma`, to create a summation symbol. The `\sum` symbol is slightly larger than `\Sigma` when used in text style, and a whole lot larger when used in display style. In addition, the math type of `\sum` is `math-op` ("math operator"), whereas the math type of `\Sigma` is `math-ord` ("ordinary atom"); this strongly affects the amount of whitespace TeX inserts before and after the symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\Sigma_{i\in V}     \beta_i \quad 
 \sum_{i\in V}       \beta_i \quad
 \sum\limits_{i\in V}\beta_i \quad
{\displaystyle\sum\nolimits_{i\in V} \beta_i} \quad
 \displaystyle\sum_{i\in V} \beta_i$
\end{document}
```